# Migrating from spring to spring boot (spring security auth not working)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-ldap

```java
@Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.csrf().and().headers().and().anonymous().disable()
                    .formLogin().loginPage("/login.html").failureHandler(this.authenticationFailureHandler)
                    .defaultSuccessUrl("/main").loginProcessingUrl("/j_spring_security_check")
                    .usernameParameter("j_username").passwordParameter("j_password")
                    .and()
                    .logout().logoutUrl("/j_spring_security_logout").logoutSuccessUrl("/login.html");
}
```

When am hitting the login button it redirects me to
[image]

Comment: you mention basic auth but have configured form login. So which is it basic auth or form based login.

Comment: @M.Deinum form auth

Comment: You need a `permitAll()` after the `passwordParemeter` to allow access else everything will be secured. You get a 403 which means you don't have access so either you aren't allowed to access that URL or to whatever you are being forwarded/redirected to .

Comment: @M.Deinum added but still getting same error

Comment: im pretty sure `j_spring_security_check` is deprecated and removed the default login url is a POST to /login with username and password as form parameters

Comment: @Toerktumlare I changed it to /login but even then am getting same error

Answer (score 0):

- Add this in your security config class
  ***.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/login*").permitAll()***
- Remove the following
  ***and().headers().and().anonymous()***

```java
@Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.csrf().disable()
                    .formLogin().loginPage("/login.html").failureHandler(this.authenticationFailureHandler)
                    .defaultSuccessUrl("/main").loginProcessingUrl("/j_spring_security_check")
                    .usernameParameter("j_username").passwordParameter("j_password")
                    .and()
                    .logout().logoutUrl("/j_spring_security_logout").logoutSuccessUrl("/login.html");
}
```